# How can I remove disabled from a button element on my page?

Tags: javascript

I am using this code to set and remove the disabled attribute on buttons on my web page:

```
if (localStorage.buttonColor) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className = localStorage.buttonColor;
    var themeButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".theme");
    for (var button in themeButtons) {
        themeButtons[button].removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
    document.querySelector('button[name="' + localStorage.buttonColor + '"]').disabled = true;
}
```

But it's giving me a message saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'removeAttribute'
```

Can someone give me advice on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat `disabled` as a property, not an attribute:

```
themeButtons[button].disabled = false;
```